# Change of point location when changing the resolution

Tags: html, css, position

I try to understand position and values absolute and relative, but I have one problem.
Why, when I use the "right" attribute, my "A" point changes position when the resolution changes, but when it applies the "left" attribute, everything stays in place well, even when I change the resolution?

Please check on different resolutions:
- Left:
[image]
- Right:
[image]

Code:
- Left:

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

main {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  min-width: 350px;
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 40vw;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.map {
  background:url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/Simple_world_map.svg/2000px-Simple_world_map.svg.png")
    no-repeat; 
  background-size: cover;
  height: 60vh;
  position: relative;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 20px;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <form>
        <div class="map">
        <div class="absolute">
          <h1>A</h1>
          </div>
      </div>
    </form>
</main>
```

- Right:

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

main {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  min-width: 350px;
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 40vw;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.map {
  background:url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/Simple_world_map.svg/2000px-Simple_world_map.svg.png")
    no-repeat; 
  background-size: cover;
  height: 60vh;
  position: relative;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  right: 447px;
  top: 20px;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <form>
        <div class="map">
        <div class="absolute">
          <h1>A</h1>
          </div>
      </div>
    </form>
</main>
```

My question is why this is happening, why the use of "right" is so unstable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the absolute position is "relative" to `.map` div that it has no fixed width (
it changes as the browser size changes, from min 350px to max 700px - 
inherits this rule from the parent `main`). So the `.map`'s right border continuously changes its position. The left border, on the other hand, "remains steady" so the h1 never change its position.

I try to explain better with an image:

[image]